# How to parse HTTP Request from a TCP connection?

Tags: http, tcp, webserver, httpserver

Let's say there's 2 HTTP requests send to http server using the same underlying TCP connection almost at the same time.

How http server identify this two HTTP requests correctly(OR how http server parse these TCP connection bytes into 2 HTTP requests correctly) ?

For example :

request 1 : 2000 bytes
request 2 : 2000 bytes

```
http client                    http server
    |---------req1 1000byte------->|  
    |---------req2 1000byte------->| 
    |---------req1 200byte-------->|
    |---------req2 1000byte------->|
    |---------req1 800byte-------->|
```

Comment: For HTTP version <2, it can't.

Comment: [An overview of HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Overview) and [w3.org - hypertext transfer protocol : Introduction](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec1.html)

Comment: By definition, HTTP requests are stateless so it doesn't matter so far as HTTP is concerned. However if you are building a protocol such as REST on top of HTTP then it is up to the higher level protocol to add any kind of stateful logic needed.

Comment: The server needs to parse the actual content of the message to determine its full size. For HTTP/1.1 message syntax is defined in [RFC 7230 section 3](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3), so please see there for details.

Comment: @tkausl If HTTP 1.1 Pipeline enabled, then how does http server identify the `read()`ed  bytes from tcp connection belongs to request 1 or request 2 ?